# Tkinter unexpected behavior, method not creating window

Tags: python, user-interface, methods, tkinter

First of all, I know this is not a question, but really need help.

I have a program that was working fine in CLI, but now I started to code the GUI with tkinter. I created a method that creates a window and recieves the date for the rest of the program. My code is as follow.

```
def getDate():

    global dayVar
    global dayMenu
    global yearVar
    global yearMenu
    global monthVar
    global monthMenu

    rt = Tk()
    print(rt.state())
    print(rt)
    rt.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    rt.minsize(height=200, width=400)
    rt.title("Selecionar Data...")

    rt.update()

    rt.attributes("-topmost", True)
    rt.attributes("-topmost", False)

    Grid.rowconfigure(rt, 0, weight=1)
    Grid.columnconfigure(rt, 0, weight=1)

    frameTop = Frame(rt)
    frameTop.grid(row=0,column=0)

    dayVar = IntVar(rt)
    monthVar = StringVar(rt)
    yearVar = IntVar(rt)

    dayVar.set(1)
    monthVar.set("Janeiro")
    yearVar.set(2015)

    dayMenu = OptionMenu(frameTop, dayVar, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,31)

    monthMenu = OptionMenu(frameTop, monthVar, "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Marco", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro","Dezembro")

    yearMenu = OptionMenu(frameTop, yearVar, "")
    for i in range(2015, datetime.datetime.today().year + 1):
        # Add a new item (i - in this case an int) to the option menu
        yearMenu['menu'].add_command(label=i, command=_setit(yearVar, i))
        yearVar.set(2015)


    #PACKING/GRIDING
    Label(frameTop, text="Dia").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=NSEW)
    Label(frameTop, text="Mes").grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=NSEW)
    Label(frameTop, text="Ano").grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=NSEW)
    dayMenu.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=NSEW)
    monthMenu.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=NSEW)
    yearMenu.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=NSEW)


    frameBottom = Frame(rt)
    frameBottom.grid(row=1,column=0)

    b = Button(rt, text="Próximo", command=rt.destroy)
    b.grid(row=1)

    rt.mainloop(1)
```

The issue is that if I run the method withou the rest of the program it loads and displays the window perfectly. When I run the whole code, it does not run in any way. Curiously it is not showing an error, it is not crasshing, and if I insert lots of prints amidst the codes that create and insert things in the window (rt is my var for the window =>"rt=Tk()") all of them are printed, it is as it ignores all of my commands in tkinter.

If there are any idea of what could be happening I would love to hear about it. I tought that the fact that I destroyed the previous window and used the same var to create this new one was the problem, so I changed the var name. It did not work

If by any mean someone need to see the whole code, just ask. I will not post it by first because it is too big, and I really hope the problem is here.
thanks in advance

Comment: Calling `Tk()` more than once during the lifetime of a program is generally a bad idea, but I don't think it can result in *nothing* appearing.  Are you sure the window isn't just showing up behind an existing window?  I've seen that happen all too often.

Comment: No, It is not, I tought this was happening too, but the problem is that the code is running goig past trough the tkinter part and ignoring the fact that I want input from that window for the code to run
This results in the vars not having values and my code crashing in the lower sections

Comment: But why souldnt I use Tk() more than once? I wish to use two screens? isnt it supposed to be separated by the var name in wich they are being inserted?

Comment: Think of the instance of `Tk()` as a thread or process. They aren't, but conceptually they are similar. Each instance of `Tk` has it's own internal namespace. Variables (`StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc) and widgets from one can't interact with variables or widgets in another. if you need multiple windows, the second and subsequent windows should be instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: Each time you call `Tk()`, a brand new instance of the embedded Tcl/Tcl environment that actually implements the GUI gets created.  Widgets, variables, etc. that are created in one environment simply will not work in another - and there's no good error message if you accidentally try to cross this boundary.

Comment: Okay, thats is really nice to know, Ill try to study it further and use this TopLeves instances instead, But My code was working just some runs before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Found the solution, thanks for [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper) to explaining why not using the Tk() method over and over.

I was using Tk.destroy() and the instance was being destroyed, and so much the reference it got. That is why the code was ignoring my new attemp in creating a window. I found out that when I use Tk.quit() the window closes and when I use Tk() again it creates a new one.

Maybe it is not the RIGHT way to do it, but for now I ll leave it like this.
There whould be a better way to removing and creating windows, and I will study the possibility of implementing withdraw and using tabs or frames to show and hide stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other problems, but one is definitely this:

```
yearMenu['menu'].add_command(label=i, command=_setit(yearVar, i))
```

The above is exactly the same as this:

```
result = _setit(yearVar, i)
yearMenu['menu'].add_command(label=i, command=result)
```

In other words, you're immediately calling `_setit` while creating the window. If that function has a side effect of destroying the window, you will get the behavior you describe.

The `command` attribute requires a *callable* -- a reference to a function. If you need to pass a parameter to the function, it's common to create a closure with `lambda`:

```
...add_command(...command=lambda i=i: _setit(yearVar, i))
```

Comment: actualy the code was running right even with this problem you noted, but I have read some things about the lambda functions and I have corrected some things.
Even after those updates the code wasnt working until I made some changes in the creation and removal of the window stance